# How to compare Chars of separate String values stored in an array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, char, compare

I have an array that contains three different strings for example:

```
[ 'obtain wealth1', 'obtain dreams3', 'obtain discretion3' ]
```

The array is created from a function I've written.

What I want to do next is compare the last characters of the strings to one another (the numbers) to see if I produce a match.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: do u just wish to see if there is a repetition in the numbers??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First loop through the array and determine (with an if statement) if the elements held at the positions in the array have, as its last character, a value equal to the number you wish. You can add else if statements to check for
multiple conditions. We use the slice method with an argument of -1 to check for the rightmost character in the string.

```
for (var i = list.length; i--;) {
    if (list[i].slice(-1) == the_number) {

    } else {}
}
```

Comment: could you explain what you're suggesting here?

Comment: @michelFeldheim We loop through the array and see if the last character in the element at index `i` is equal to `the_number` (which is a variable equal to a number). Is this what you're wanting.

Comment: Yip, perfect :) add this to the answer

Answer (score 0):

With string functions for example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

```js
var a = [ 'obtain wealth1', 'obtain dreams3', 'obtain discretion3' ];
var length = a.length;
var lastchar = a.charAt(length - 1);
```